# Inheritance from non-protocol type 'DarwinBoolean' - Migration to swift 3

Tags: swift

I migrate my code to Swift 3. the error was:

> Inheritance from non-protocol type 'DarwinBoolean'

for this section of code:

---

```
extension XMLIndexer:DarwinBoolean {
/// True if a valid XMLIndexer, false if an error type
public var boolValue: Bool {
    get {
        switch self {
        case .error:
            return false
        default:
            return true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions about the problem?

Comment: What did the (working) code look like in Swift 2? DarwinBoolean is a struct, not a protocol, so `extension XMLIndexer:DarwinBoolean` cannot compile in any Swift version.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. I've contacted the editor of source code, they say that the app doesn 't support the swift 3 yet. and they give me the right code on version 2.3 which work perfectly.
extension XMLIndexer: BooleanType {
    /// True if a valid XMLIndexer, false if an error type
    public var boolValue: Bool {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Error:
                return false
            default:
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
i share may be it can help someone.

Comment: `BooleanType` is a protocol which is removed from Swift 3. You can define your own `BooleanType` protocol, if you want that extension -- `public protocol BooleanType {var boolValue: Bool { get }}`. But just removing `:DarwinBoolean` from your code would be a better way.